# How slowly can a brushless DC motor spin?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Obviously dependent on the internal design of the bearings and the rolling friction.

Otherwise, is the slowest rpm for a brushless motor related to the number of poles the motor is designed with?

Comment: Depends what's driving it. If you drive it open loop like micro-stepping a stepper, I don't see a lower limit.

Comment: How low do you need?

Comment: This is really a question of drive electronics, motor design, and required torque.  A typical "brushless motor" won't have the torque to produce much power at negligible speed.  A physically massive stepper motor might be built in such a way that it has a moderate low speed torque.  Depending on the application requirement, it may make more sense to use a small motor with mechanical reduction than a large one direct drive.  **To get a useful answer you will need to state your application requirements - maximum speed, torque at low speed, mass and power tolerance, etc, and what it is for**

Comment: Gentlemen, look up industrial DDR motors. They are optimized for torque rather than speed. But the funny part is that they are the same brushless motors.

Comment: @Jackson Harvey, I am a BLDC motor newbie. You said "it depends on ... ***bearings  rolling friction***" Newbie me would think that you forgot the important thing - ***GEAR***!

Comment: We’ve used brushless motors in machine tools that can achieve velocities below 1 um / s.

Comment: @user110971 With gearing, of course.  You're talking about linear velocity of a part on a screw or geared stage being turned by a DC motor.  It's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @J... Gearing to provide enough torque to move the load. The speed range is from 10 m / s all the way down to 1 um / s with the same transmission.

Comment: @user110971 Sure, I'm just saying that it doesn't tell us anything about the minimum rotation speed that the motor is running at.  Maybe your top speed is 10krpm and your minimum is 0.001rpm.  Maybe your top speed is 1k rpm and your minimum motor speed is 0.0001rpm.  The question is asking about the motor speed.  Even at 10k/0.001, that's almost one day for the motor to turn once.  I'm sceptical that this is all on one gear - surely you have several gears and speed ranges in that transmission.

Comment: What's the minimum amount of torque you require from the motor? If the minimum can near 0 (a useless motor when under load), the amount of rpm can near zero too.

Comment: Torque in brushless motors doesn't depend on speed within a very broad range. Actually it does depend only when the speed becomes high, until then- you get what you want.

Comment: As a developer of servo for a long time, i disagree. The torque is limited to a safe operation area at all times. Basically, there is the allowed continuous current that defines torque, and there is allowed peak current, and in advanced systems, the peaks are throttled to prevent motor overheat. And the only relation to speed is that below certain speed the motor is declared stuck if torque is above a certain value for a certain period of time.

Comment: But the point is, low speed is where you need the most torque anyway. Allowing torque only on high speed is maybe something useful for propulsion applications, not in robotic servo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brushless DC motor can be operated as a stepper motor. Operating stepwise, it can operate as slowly as you want. Smooth operation would be more difficult. Determining that would probably require a simulation with complete characterization of the motor, controller and load.

Of course, the motor cooling would also need to be considered.

If a "typical" brushless motor and controller are defined as those designed to drive a fan or a drone propellor, operation below 1/3 of rated speed is probably not advisable except for as short a time as possible when starting and stopping. Very little torque required at low speed with that kind of application. With the right controller design, these motors are probably capable of producing the same torque at standstill as at rated speed, but thermal limitations would severely limit low speed operating time.

Brushless motors and controllers that are designed to drive electric bicycles, motorcycles and cars can be expected to be much more capable of low-speed operation. With the best controller design, they can probably operate at very low speeds. The thermal limitations would not be as severe as with fan and propellor motors, but still an important limitation.

The number of poles is not necessarily important. Quantified speed, torque and other requirements are  more important than anything else. Load characteristics are important. Duty cycle is important. The ratio of the slowest to the highest required speed may be important.

Comment: Brushless motors are used not just in high speed applications. Industrial brushless motors are a standard solution for any robotics or machinery. In fact, the basic motion is point-to-point, which is obviously about the low to zero speeds.

Comment: Yes, for really low speed operation it would be servo motors and not steppers that would be favoured.  Steppers, as you say, are not smooth at low speeds while servos are, and their accuracy can be phenomenal with good encoders.  As long as the load doesn't go over the peak torque a servo can go, effectively, as slowly as you like, and can even just stay stopped exactly where you want it indefinitely.  The controllers are electronic, so the thermal limit really just turns into a low-speed torque limit (with headroom for momentary operation up to 3-400% of rated torque, if for a short time).

Answer (score 4):

The more poles a brushless motor has, the smoother it will spin at low RPM with a trapezoid/square wave drive. But if you just use a sinusoidal drive then it doesn't really matter. Of course you still need an appropriate rotor feedback mechanism for the RPM you are spinning at. Some are ineffective at low speeds. So it's more about the drive than it is about the motor.

Comment: Come on, I move a two-pole motor with the accuracy of micro radians. It's absolutely not related to the number of magnets, only to the control method.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Which is what I said.

Comment: You talk about more poles, which is irrelevant and misleading

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Only if you do not read the full answer. If you're stuck with a trapezoidal drive, as many are, then you really do need more poles.

Answer (score 3):

The brushless motor can spin at any low speed. Maintaining low speed smooth may require some algorithms, feedback hardware and stuff, but is totally doable. For example with incremental encoder you can use 1/T method (measure time between pulses rather than count them) to sense the speed. With high resolution encoders even that may be not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend primarily on the controller. The BLDC controller's job is to adjust the coil current direction based on rotor position. There are three common ways the rotor position is determined, in order from most common to least common:

1. **Sensorless back-EMF voltage control:** detects the voltage caused by the spinning rotor. It usually only works well at higher speeds, typically minimum is about 5% of the maximum speed of the system.
2. **Sensored control with encoders / Hall sensors**: uses separate sensors to detect rotor position. Works well at even standstill, though some controllers may have torque ripple and vibration at slow speeds.
3. **Sensorless high-frequency injection:** Applies high-frequency square wave to each coil in turn, and detects the field induced on other coils. The magnetic field of the rotor affects this and the rotor position can be determined. This requires per-motor calibration to have been executed before use, but will work well even at standstill. Usually found only in high-end controllers.

If separate sensors are used (case 2.), there will be 4-6 thin wires in addition to the 3 thick motor phase wires. Otherwise the control system is likely sensorless back-EMF based, and will have a definite minimum speed.

The minimum speed of a sensorless system will depend on the accuracy of voltage sensing in the controller, and the noise added by the motor driving. To optimize a system for low speed operation, one should:

1. Select a motor with low **KV** number. This coefficient determines the relationship of supply voltage and speed: for example a 1000 KV motor would spin at 1000 RPM with 1 V supply voltage. This is determined by the number of poles and slots, and also by the number of turns in coil windings.
2. Use the lowest supply voltage that achieves the necessary speed. The lower the supply voltage, the slower the current in the coils will change and the less noise this introduces to the back-EMF sensing.

At slowest speeds, also the driving waveform used by the controller will matter. Simplest controllers use 6-step square wave driving, which will cause noticeable vibration and stepwise movement. More advanced controllers will have sine wave driving, which gives smoother movement.